# Mobile view emulator, Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, mobile, scale

I want to "emulate" how site will look in phone.
So, for example next code:

```
<div>
    <div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      First
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      Second
    </div>
</div>
```

Must always look in xs-12 version of site.
I tried to use `<meta id="viewport" name=viewport content="width=200px; initial-scale=1">` , but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I need to show to user mobile view of site, by clicking button(for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use google chrome dev tools and emulate mobile experience: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode It helps you to emulate not only the user agent but geolocation and other device stuff

Comment: I add comment above:
"I need to show to user mobile view of site, by clicking button(for example)."

Answer (score 0):

Well... it's going to have the same effect as replicating the resolution in your brower *eg*. [Resizer](http://resizesafari.com/) (mobile safari)  or using a website that does it [iPadPeek](http://www.ipadpeek.com)

Your browser is not going to read `<meta>` viewport information. In which case you will not get the full mobile 'view' or experience.

If your trying to do this on a actual mobile device (which wouldn't be an emulator); and it doesn't work you'll need to show the CSS styles that relate. Meta viewport declarations work with CSS3 media queries.

Now, if you want to create a button to open a new window that is of a mobile size.. you can do the below.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=320, height=460");
}
</script>
```

But again, this wouldn't be a full mobile replication.. only a pop-up of similar resolution.

Comment: How it is possible to do in a current page?

Comment: It is not new questions, maybe my poor English can not allow me to explain lucidly, I didn't get nothing new from this 2 answers=(